# Find version of JRE installed and install it if not found

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a subroutine that checks for the Java Runtime path in the registry and if it isn't found, attempts to install it. There is an error in my code somewhere but I've been staring at it too long and can't find it. The output I get when I run it is:

```
Running Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 3
Installing HermesJMS.
Checking Java Runtime install path.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in the :FindJRE subroutine. Any help much appreciated. Here is my code.

```
::@echo off
setlocal

call :GetOSVer os sp
Echo Running %os% %sp%
call :sleep 2
set key="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
ECHO Installing HermesJMS.
call :sleep 2
::hermes-installer-1.14.jar
echo Checking Java Runtime install path.
call :sleep 2
call :FindJRE jre
call :sleep 2
echo Setting Java_Home path.
call :sleep 2
reg add %key% /v JAVA_HOME /t REG_SZ /d %jre% /f>nul
For /f "tokens=3 delims=    " %%a in ('reg query %key% /v JAVA_HOME^|Find "JAVA_HOME"') do (
     Echo Java home path set to: %%a.
)
call :sleep 2
echo Checking for Capitalware...
call :sleep 2
if not exist "C:\Capitalware" (
    echo Installing Capitalware
    "%~dp0Capitalware\Windows\mqce-setup.exe"
)   
call :sleep 2
Echo You can now run HermesJMS.
call :sleep 5
pause
exit /b

:Sleep
@echo off & setlocal
Ping -n %1 127.0.0.1 >nul
exit /b

:GetOSVer
@echo off
set key="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
  'reg query %key% /v ProductName') do (
   set "%~1=%%a"
)
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
  'reg query %key% /v CSDVersion') do (
   set "%~2=%%a"
)
exit /b

:FindJRE
::@echo off
setlocal
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN (
  `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v CurrentVersion 2^>nul`
  ) DO ( set Val=%%~A )
    if defined Val (
        echo.the current Java runtime is %Val%
    ) else ( 
        echo.%KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
            for /f %%a in ('dir /b jre*') do (
                Echo.Attempting to install Java Runtime Environment. 
                echo.Flipping the junkware bit
                REG add HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft /v Sponsors /t REG_SZ /d Disable > nul 
                set loc="%%a" 
                    If defined %loc% ( %loc% 
                    ) ELSE (
                        Echo.Java installer not found. Please download the latest Java Runtime Environment from the Oracle Website.
                        exit /b 1
                    )       
            )
    )
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A IN (
  `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME%\%Val% /v JavaHome 2^>nul`
  ) DO ( 
  endlocal
  set %~1="%%~A %%~B"
)
exit /b 0
```

**Updated Version - Fully Working**

```
:: HermesJMS install script ::
:: Author - Matt Williamson ::
:: Rev 1 -     02/13/15     ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

@echo off
setlocal

call :GetOSVer os sp
Echo Running %os% %sp%
call :sleep 2
set key="HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
ECHO Installing HermesJMS.
call :sleep 2
hermes-installer-1.14.jar
echo Checking Java install path.
call :sleep 2
call :FindJRE jre

If not %jre% EQU dec (
    call :sleep 2
    echo Setting Java home path.
    call :sleep 2
    reg add %key% /v JAVA_HOME /t REG_SZ /d %jre% /f >nul
        For /f "skip=4 tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query %key% /v JAVA_HOME') do (
            Echo Java home path set to: %%a %%b
        )
)   ELSE ( Endlocal&echo You must install Java Runtime Environment for Hermes to work.&exit /b 1)   
call :sleep 2
echo Checking for Capitalware...
call :sleep 2
if not exist "C:\Capitalware" (
    echo Installing Capitalware
    "%~dp0Capitalware\Windows\mqce-setup.exe"
)   
call :sleep 5
echo Now running HermesJMS
"C:\Program Files\HermesJMS\bin\hermes.bat"
exit /b 0 

:Sleep
@echo off & setlocal
Ping -n %1 127.0.0.1 >nul
exit /b

:GetOSVer
@echo off
set key="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
for /f "skip=4 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
  'reg query %key% /v ProductName') do (
   set "%~1=%%a"
)
for /f "skip=4 tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
  'reg query %key% /v CSDVersion') do (
   set "%~2=%%a"
)
exit /b

:FindJRE
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "aux1= "
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=3" %%A IN (
  `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v CurrentVersion 2^>nul`
  ) DO ( set "Val=%%~A" )
    if defined Val (
        echo.the current Java runtime is !Val!
    ) else ( 
        echo.Java Runtime Environment not found.
            for /f %%a in ('dir /b jre*') do (
                Echo.Attempting to install Java Runtime Environment. 
                set "loc=%%a"
                    If defined loc ( 
                        echo.Flipping the junkware bit
                        REG add HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft /v Sponsors /t REG_SZ /d Disable /f>nul
                        Call :SpinnerEx&!loc!
                        Set Key2="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft"
                            FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=3" %%G IN (
                                `REG QUERY !Key2! /v InstallStatus 2^>nul`) do (
                                    If "%%G" EQU "decline" (
                                        Echo JRE install cancelled
                                        Endlocal&Set %~1=dec&exit /b 1
                                    )
                            )

                    ) ELSE (
                        Echo.Java installer not found. Please download the latest Java Runtime Environment from the Oracle Website.
                        exit /b 1
                    )       
            )
    )
FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=3*" %%A IN (
  `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME%\%Val% /v JavaHome 2^>nul`
  ) DO ( 
  set "aux1=%%~A %%~B"
)
endlocal&set %~1="%aux1%"&exit /b 0  

:SpinnerEx
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

FOR /L %%n in (1,1,10) DO (
    call :spinner
    ping localhost -n 1 > nul
)
exit /b

:spinner
set /a "spinner=(spinner + 1) %% 4"
set "spinChars=\|/-"
<nul set /p ".=Waiting for JRE...!spinChars:~%spinner%,1!!CR!"
exit /b
```

Comment: Where does the error occur if you leave echo on?

Comment: Forgotten `echo.the current Java runtime is %Val%`, should be `!Val!`

Comment: I just took it from your code but the odd thing is, it was working **without** delayedexpansion! Now, that's going to bug me trying to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the error is in the `:FindJRE` subroutine. Here is an attempt to correct it (but I don't claim completeness):

- `@echo on` helps to locate error source line
- [read more](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) about `enabledelayedexpansion` and using `!var!` instead of `%var%`
- `echo REG add ...` command `echo`ed as I do not want do it really for apprehensible reason :)
- `echo !loc!` detto (as well)
- `set "Val=%%~A"` the best practice to set value to a variable to ensure there are no trailing spaces
- `If defined loc (` instead of that strange weird `If defined %loc% (`
- `endlocal&set %~1="%aux1%"&exit /b 0` trick to set output (by reference) variable:

  - using previously defined auxiliary `aux` variable
  - another trick to ensure there are no trailing spaces: `set %~1="%aux1%"` surrounded by `&` ampersand characters
- **note** the output `"%aux1%"` could result to `" "`, i.e. a space surrounded with `"` quotation marks
- sorry if any correction forgotten and hence not listed here...

The code:

```
:FindJRE
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "aux1= "
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN (
  `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v CurrentVersion 2^>nul`
  ) DO ( set "Val=%%~A" )
    if defined Val (
        echo the current Java runtime is %Val%
    ) else ( 
        echo.%KEY_NAME%\%VALUE_NAME% not found.
            for /f %%a in ('dir /b jre*') do (
                Echo.Attempting to install Java Runtime Environment. 
                echo.Flipping the junkware bit
                echo REG add HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft /v Sponsors /t REG_SZ /d Disable > nul 
                set loc="%%a" 

                    If defined loc ( 
                      echo !loc! 
                    ) ELSE (
                        Echo.Java installer not found. Please download the latest Java Runtime Environment from the Oracle Website.
                        exit /b 1
                    )       
            )
    )
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A IN (
  `REG QUERY %KEY_NAME%\%Val% /v JavaHome 2^>nul`
  ) DO ( 
  set "aux1=%%~A %%~B"
)
endlocal&set %~1="%aux1%"&exit /b 0
```

Comment: Very good, All things that I forgot about since I haven't written batch scripts for over a year. I have updated my original post with the fully working version.